# How to write buffer contents to external program and put the output into the quickfix window?

Tags: vim

So I know you can pipe the current buffer contents to an external program with `w!sometool` and I know you can use cexpr to display e.g. a variable's contents to the quickfix window, but I can't work out how to do both at the same time.

Basically, I want to do the following:

`:cexpr w!sometool --stdin`

But I can't figure out how to get vim to treat the part after cexpr as a vim command to run.

I already have errorformat set to match the output.

Alternatively, if there's a way to use the makeprg system to run makeprg in tha same way (current unsaved buffer contents to stdin), that would be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the point is that in VimScript commands and expressions are different things. So you cannot simply do that composition of `command1 command2 command3` like with the expressions. (Yes, there exists `:w !sometool`, but this is not two commands pasted together, but rather a single command with a unique syntax).

So you must execute `:cexpr some_expr`, and not `:cexpr some_command`. This can be achieved by using function `system()` (or `systemlist()`), as any function call (without the preceding command `:call`) is an expression in VimScript:

```
:cexpr system('sometool', bufnr())
```

Comment: bufnr() is supposed to spit out the buffer number, not the buffer contents.  I looked at :help bufnr and browsed all the commands that start with buf and don't see one that does what I need.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JasonBurnett `bufnr()` is an argument for `system()`. Have you read `:h system()` until the end?

Comment: Yes.  When it didn't initially work, I looked at :help bufnr, which says nothing about the buffer contents, but I see now that system does that bit when it gets a buffer number.   So the final challenge is that when I run this, and then open the quickfix list with copen, it shows the correct output, but pressing enter on one of them or using :cnext/prev don't actually jump to the line.  My errorformat is "%f:\ line\ %l\\,\ col\ %c\\,\ %m,%-G%.%#" and a sample output line is "<text>: line 1, col 19, Error - Extra semicolon. (semi)"

Comment: @JasonBurnett This is written under `:h system()` "When {input} is given and is a **number** that is a valid id for an existing buffer then **the content of the buffer** is written..." etc.etc. If the jump doesn't work then your `errorformat` is bugged.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the errorformat issue and I'm all set.   Thanks a ton!